# swift - How sort alphabetically annotations array

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit, mkannotation

My project is a map with a lot of annotations points, and user could look for a specific annotation thanks to a pickerView. All is fine except the list of all annotations points seems randomly displayed. I would like to sort the annotations alphabetically.

Here s my current working code :

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return self.mapView.annotations[row].title ?? "No title"

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.mapView.annotations[row], animated: true)
    }
```

I ve tried to implement this, but without any success...

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

let sortedNames = self.mapView.annotations.sorted(by: {$0.title < $1.title})
        return sortedNames[row].title ?? "No title"

    }
```

I ve got this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String??' to expected argument type
>   'UIContentSizeCategory'

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just sort the list of names that you used to create your annotations, rather than trying to sort your annotations?  It's worth pointing out that `sortedNames` is actually an array of `MKMapAnnotation` sorted by title.  If you really need to do it that way you could turn it into an array of Strings like this: `let sortedNames = self.mapView.annotations.sorted(by: {$0.title < $1.title}).flatMap({ $0.title })`

Comment: It also doesn't seem very smart to sort the whole list alphabetically for each row in your picker.  Why not just maintain one list of titles so you can sort once, and then just continue accessing that list when getting titles for your picker?

Comment: Because the order of annotations changes each time, i made the request for annotation... and i only have 25 annotations .

Answer (score 8):

I'm aware this question is a bit old to answer but for anyone else having the issue the problem is that the String can not be optional. The fix it to either provide a default value or force unwrap it. For example this would be one solution to the question:

```
let sortedNames = self.mapView.annotations.sorted(by: { ($0.title ?? "") < ($1.title ?? "") }))
return sortedNames[row].title ?? "No title"
```

Comment: That's it bro! Works like a charm ?) +1

Comment: No working...Still this error `Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'String?' operands`

Comment: @KeghamK. That means they're still optional Strings. You need to provide a default value which will turn them from 'String?' into 'String'. This will allow you to compare them with a binary operator.

Comment: @JackHopkins found the issue. The type of `MKAnnotation.title` is `String??`, it's a nested `Optional`, so you need to optional bind it twice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605162/if-let-doesnt-unwrap-optional-value-for-mkannotations-title-property

Answer (score 0):

I've just had exactly this error when trying to sort an array of a different class by a string property. The problem appears to be that the property you are sorting by is optional. Using a non-optional property works as expected, using an optional property gives the somewhat bizarre 'UIContentSizeCategory' error.

Something like this should do what you need:

```
   let sorted = self.mapView.annotations { (a1, a2) -> Bool in
            if let s1 = a1.title {
                if let s2 = a2.title {
                    return s1 > s2
                }
            }
            return false
        }
```