# if let doesn't unwrap optional value for MKAnnotation's title property

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation

I want to unwrap optional value with if-let statement.
I need to get title of MKAnnotation.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let title = view.annotation?.title {
        print(title) //Optional("Moscow")
    }
}
```

Why if-let doesn't work here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `MKAnnotation.title` is `String??`, it's a nested `Optional`, so you need to optional bind it twice.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let optionalTitle = view.annotation?.title, let title = optionalTitle {
        print(title)
    }
}
```

Even though according to the [documentation of MKAnnotation.title](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotation/1429522-title), the type of title should be `String?`, since `title` is declared as a non-required protocol property:

```
optional var title: String? { get }
```

when accessed through the `MKAnnotation` protocol type rather than the concrete type implementing the protocol, it becomes wrapped in another `Optional`, which represents the fact that the `title` property might not even be implemented by the concrete type implementing the protocol. Hence, when accessing the `title` property of an `MKAnnotation` object rather than an object with a concrete type conforming to `MKAnnotation`, the type of `title` will be `String??`.

Comment: I just wonder: optional chaining does usually does *not* give nested optionals: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html: *"If the type you are trying to retrieve is already optional, it will not become more optional because of the chaining."*

Comment: @MartinR it is not optional chaining that makes `title` nested optional, check `if let annotation = view.annotation, let title = annotation.title {...}` or even force unwrapping `view.annotation`, the `title` will still be a nested optional, even though according to the documentation, it should not be.

Comment: But `view.annotation?.title`  should be a *simple* optional due to the above rule, and unwrapping it should give a non-optional string. What am I overlooking?

Comment: `MKAnnotation` is a protocol, so it's something in the OP's conforming class. You can get the same behaviour using… `class Test: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let title: String?? = "Hello"
}` @subdan could you add your annotation class to the question?

Comment: @AshleyMills the `MKAnnotation` is accessed through a `MKAnnotationView` in the above function, so there's no custom class conforming to the protocol, it is the built-in `MKAnnotationView` class whose `annotation` property is accessed

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct - the `MKAnnotationView` created in `mapView(_ mapView:viewFor:)` which takes an annotation object. There must be a conforming class

Comment: @AshleyMills just try copy-pasting that single function to a playground after importing `MapKit` and you'll see that the type is the unexpected nested-optional without creating any custom conforming types

Comment: Oh… interesting.! The mystery deepens.

Comment: @MartinR as I've said, the optional chaining rule doesn't apply here, since both the `title` and `subtitle` properties are of the unexpected nested optional type when force unwrapping `annotation`, so it cannot be the optional chaining that causes the issue. I'm not sure what are we overlooking either, since the documentation clearly states that these should be simple `Optional`s, but for some reason the compiler thinks they're nested ones.

Comment: The issue seems to be caused by the Objective-C `optional` modifier, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/davidpasztor/6339b601571e1dec2ef083890147e77a) for a custom `Annotation` protocol that can be used to reproduce the same problem. For a property declared as `optional`, the nested Optional issue arises, while for a required property it doesn't. This seems like a bug to me, but please confirm that I'm not overlooking any details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181140/discussion-between-ashley-mills-and-david-pasztor).

Comment: I've raised a bug about this and apparently this is [intended behaviour](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8903).