# Can you safely unwrap nested optionals in swift in one line?

Tags: swift

I'm currently using four lines to unwrap the title from `mapViewDidSelectMKAnnotationView`.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let title = view.annotation?.title {
        if let title = title {
            // do something with title
        }
    }
}
```

Can I do this without having to unwrap things twice? Something like:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let title = view.annotation?.title? {
        // do something with title
    }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548999/unwrapping-multiple-optionals-in-if-statement) seems to get really close to the question but doesn't address the case of the deepest property being an optional. It seems like a pretty trivial thing and I'm certain there must be a way but I can't work out the syntax for the life of me.

Comment: See [if let doesn't unwrap optional value for MKAnnotation's title property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52605162/if-let-doesnt-unwrap-optional-value-for-mkannotations-title-property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like so:

```
if let title = view.annotation?.title as? String {

}
```

`view.annotation?.title` is a double optional string: `String??` since both the property `annotation` of an `MKAnnotationView`, and its own property `title`, are optional.

---

You could also use the *guard* statement like so:

```
guard let title = view.annotation?.title as? String else {
    return 
}
//use title in the rest of the scope
```

---

you could also use a `switch` statement :

```
switch title {
case .some(.some(let t)):
    //use the title here
    print(t)
default:
    break 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To unwrap to a single optional string, you can use

`let title = (view.annotation.title ?? nil)`

You can then use null coalescing to fall back to a default string:

`let title = (view.annotation.title ?? nil) ?? "fallback string"`